# Lucene: Wildcard not matching number after dot

Tags: java, lucene

I recently upgraded from Lucene 3 to Lucene 6, and in v6 I found out that the wildcard `?` doesn't match numbers following dots anymore. Here's an example:

string to match: `a.1a`

query: `a.?a`

In this example, the query matches the string in Lucene 3, but *not* in Lucene 6. On the other hand, the query `a*` matches in both Lucene 3 and 6. Further testing indicates that this difference in behavior only occurs when a dot is followed by a number. I'm using the `StandardAnalyzer` in both Lucene 3 and 6, by the way.

Does anybody know what's going on here? How can I restore the behavior of Lucene 3, or alternatively, adapt my Lucene 6 query so that it's equivalent to the Lucene 3 ones?

**UPDATE**

Lucene 6.6 code snippet as requested.

```
public List<ResultDocument> search(String queryString)
        throws SearchException, CheckedOutOfMemoryError {
    stopped =false;

    QueryWrapper queryWrapper = createQuery(queryString);
    Query query = queryWrapper.query;
    boolean isPhraseQuery = queryWrapper.isPhraseQuery;

    readLock.lock();
    try {
        checkIndexesExist();

        DelegatingCollector collector= new DelegatingCollector(){
            @Override
            public void collect(int doc) throws IOException {
                leafDelegate.collect(doc);
                if(stopped){
                    throw new StoppedSearcherException();
                }
            }
        };
        collector.setDelegate(TopScoreDocCollector.create(MAX_RESULTS, null));
        try{
            luceneSearcher.search(query, collector);
        }
        catch (StoppedSearcherException e){}
        ScoreDoc[] scoreDocs = ((TopScoreDocCollector)collector.getDelegate()).topDocs().scoreDocs;

        ResultDocument[] results = new ResultDocument[scoreDocs.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < scoreDocs.length; i++) {
            Document doc = luceneSearcher.doc(scoreDocs[i].doc);
            float score = scoreDocs[i].score;
            LuceneIndex index = indexes.get(((DecoratedMultiReader) luceneSearcher.getIndexReader()).decoratedReaderIndex(i));
            IndexingConfig config = index.getConfig();
            results[i] = new ResultDocument(
                doc, score, query, isPhraseQuery, config, fileFactory,
                outlookMailFactory);
        }
        return Arrays.asList(results);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw wrapEmptyIndexException(e);
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new SearchException(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        throw new CheckedOutOfMemoryError(e);
    }
    finally {
        readLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

More code:

```
private static QueryWrapper createQuery(String queryString)
        throws SearchException {
    PhraseDetectingQueryParser queryParser = new PhraseDetectingQueryParser(
        Fields.CONTENT.key(), IndexRegistry.getAnalyzer());
    queryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
    RewriteMethod rewriteMethod = MultiTermQuery.SCORING_BOOLEAN_REWRITE;
    queryParser.setMultiTermRewriteMethod(rewriteMethod);

    try {
        Query query = queryParser.parse(queryString);
        boolean isPhraseQuery = queryParser.isPhraseQuery();
        return new QueryWrapper(query, isPhraseQuery);
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        throw new SearchException(e.getMessage());
    }
    catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new SearchException(e.getMessage());
    }
}

private static final class QueryWrapper {
    public final Query query;
    public final boolean isPhraseQuery;

    private QueryWrapper(Query query, boolean isPhraseQuery) {
        this.query = query;
        this.isPhraseQuery = isPhraseQuery;
    }
}
```

Even more code:

```
public final class PhraseDetectingQueryParser extends QueryParser {

    /*
     * This class is used for determining whether the parsed query is supported
     * by the fast-vector highlighter. The latter only supports queries that are
     * a combination of TermQuery, PhraseQuery and/or BooleanQuery.
     */

    private boolean isPhraseQuery = true;

    public PhraseDetectingQueryParser(  String defaultField,
                                        Analyzer analyzer) {
        super(defaultField, analyzer);
    }

    public boolean isPhraseQuery() {
        return isPhraseQuery;
    }

    protected Query newFuzzyQuery(  Term term,
                                    float minimumSimilarity,
                                    int prefixLength) {
        isPhraseQuery = false;
        return super.newFuzzyQuery(term, minimumSimilarity, prefixLength);
    }

    protected Query newMatchAllDocsQuery() {
        isPhraseQuery = false;
        return super.newMatchAllDocsQuery();
    }

    protected Query newPrefixQuery(Term prefix) {
        isPhraseQuery = false;
        return super.newPrefixQuery(prefix);
    }

    protected Query newWildcardQuery(org.apache.lucene.index.Term t) {
        isPhraseQuery = false;
        return super.newWildcardQuery(t);
    }

}
```

Comment: could you show your lucene query that you're running in Lucene 6?

Comment: @Mysterion: I've added the relevant code in my post.

Comment: I mean, the most interested part is createQuery()

Comment: @Mysterion: Okay, I've added more code. I guess there's just too much funky stuff going on with the queries...?

Answer (score 0):

StandardAnalyzer splits input into terms at the period (unless there is a letter on either side of it or a number on either side of it). So it splitting that into two terms: 'a' and '1a'

Since you are using a wildcard query, no analysis is being done on the query end, so that isn't getting tokenized, and there aren't any terms in the index that match the query. If you were to search for "1a", no wildcards or anything, you should find that document.

Comment: Unfortunately, you’re not correct, there is a special parser which will do analysis for wildcard queries as well

Comment: @Mysterion - What you mean is: My explanation of the behavior they are seeing *is correct*, and you have an alternate solution. Also, 80% sure this won't actually work for the case stated. Not testing, because that parser has been removed in lucene 7, but it's not likely it's going to split `a.?a` into a multi-term query.

Comment: I’m specifically against stating that wildcard queries couldn’t be analyzed, since it’s not true. In Lucene 7 you could try factory methods from QueryParserBase

Comment: @Mysterion - Okay, but your stating you have a solution, when your stated solution doesn't actually solve this problem. The reason that parser is gone is because normalization was added to analyzers. Basically, it was only useful for normalization, not for full tokenization and analysis, which is what the solution you are giving would demand.

Comment: This answer is informative, but unfortunately doesn't solve the problem, and the QueryParserBase approach or whatever would be overkill for me in this odd corner case :-( Guess there's no going back to the Lucene 3 wildcard behavior...

Comment: @pythondude - The most likely solution is to rethink your analysis. I don't have the information to tell you what the correct one to use is. If you are trying to search some sort of identifier that really shouldn't be tokenized at all, then try using a StringField. If you really just want the old analyzer back, use ClassicAnalyzer, though bear in mind that you are trading getting this query working again with overall better, more refined analysis.

Comment: @femtoRgon: The program is intended for general-purpose search by lots of low-tech users, so it's not a serious problem if Lucene is acting up in some corner cases :-/